# Gigabit router seems to only support 100mbps WAN?

Tags: router, connection, internet-connection, gigabit-ethernet, wan

I have 2 Dlink gigabit routers. not connected at the same time though. i bought the DIR-855L to replace the DIR-655. They are listed as Gigabit both WAN and LAN. But my 200mbps internet only comes out the routers as 100mbps. my computer connected to modem directly isnt having any bandwidth issues. 
im also using Cat5e cables. 
What could be the issue? The hardware in the router just doesnt support it? OR is there some kind of software switch thats off by default that i need on?

I have contacted Dlink support. no reply yet.

Comment: Depending on how you are connecting (DHCP, PPPoE, ...), the router’s CPU may simply not be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet, it **does** support Gigabit Ethernet in its WAN port, and according to [the manual](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-855L/REVA/DIR-855L_MANUAL_1.00_EN.PDF), page 93 of the PDF, you can set the WAN port speed manually under the **Advanced network settings** page from the configuration site. You can check that it isn't being forced down to 100Mbps in the configuration and you can try to force it to 1000Mbps.

Should you find that it's set to *Auto*, check what speed is being negotiated between your computer and your router. If you find that it's less than 1000Mbps (usually shown as 1Gbps), try reseating or replacing the cable that connects your router to your computer.

If the computer is negotiating the speed correctly, try reseating or replacing the cable that connects your modem to your router. Also, verify that it's not too long and route it away from power cables as they can cause interferences in unshielded data cables.